# How to pass NavController in a HorizontalPager in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have horizontal pager as below.

```
@Composable
fun TabsContent(tabs: List<MyTabItem>, pagerState: PagerState) {
    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, pageCount = tabs.size) { page ->
        tabs[page].screen()
    }
}
```

The MyTabItem is as below

```
typealias ComposableFun = @Composable () -> Unit
sealed class MyTabItem(
    var icon_filled: Int,
    var icon_unfilled: Int,
    var title: String,
    var screen: ComposableFun,
) {
    object View :
        MyTabItem(
            R.drawable.ic_view,
            R.drawable.ic_view,
            "View",
            { ViewScreen() },
        )

    object Save: MyTabItem(
        R.drawable.ic_add_save,
        R.drawable.ic_add_save,
        "Save",
        { CreateScreen() },
    )
}
```

I want to pass the navContoller to the TabsContent Method, which needs to be accessed via Viewscreen(). How to pass it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `navContoller.navigate(tabs[page].title /*route path*/)`, and u should by setup `NavHost`.

You can take look this doc:
[Url](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)

Comment: I have already setup "navController" as per the document. Wanted to know, how i can pass it as an argument to ViewScreen Via TabContent.

Comment: Ok, i think i got u, if u set "NavHost" same document after that u can find "navController" without pass argument if defined variable "NavController" in header class and connected with "NavHost", you can now set this line "navContoller.navigate(tabs[page].title /*route path*/)"